# How to get an iterable for scikit-learn partial_fit

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am trying to train the `SGDClassifier` with text data using the `HashingVectorizer`. I wonder how I could assemble the batches which are passed to `partial_fit()` reading from multiple files.

Is the following code an appropriate way to get the data in batches via an iterable? Is there any best practice or recommended way for doing this?

```
class MyIterable:
def __init__(self, files, batch_size):
    self.files = files
    self.batch_size = batch_size
def __iter__(self):
    batchstartmark = 0
    for line in fileinput.input(self.files):
        while batchstartmark < self.batch_size
            yield line.split('\t')
            batchstartmark += 1
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please explain more about what you want to do?

Answer (score 1):

**Just judging the theory of this approach here:**
 That's a very very bad approach!

As `SGDClassifier` is using **Stochastic Gradient Descent** (using mini-batches if you want), you should try to fulfill the assumptions of [SGDs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stochastic_gradient_descent) mathematical analysis.

The basic idea of SGD is: **pick some random element and descent**.  Your code obviously diverges by two points:

- A) You are picking your elements in the same order in every epoch
- B) You are *sampling* (not really) *without replacement*

  - So x17 will not get picked until every other x was picked in this epoch

Your ignorance of **A** will lead to very bad performance with some high probability.

The point **B** is hard to analyze. There are different theoretical views, mostly dependent on some specific problem (of course there are differences between convex and non-convex problems), and while *sampling-with-replacement* is the classic one (with the most general convergence proofs), sometimes *sampling-without-replacement* (aka: shuffle and iterate during epoch / cycling) is used and often it's faster in convergence.

Comment: You're right, thank you! Until now I always used classifier.fit(), because my data fit into RAM, which by default shuffles the data.